# How to search and send notifications to people nearby in flutter firebase app?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need a way to search for people nearby and send them a push notification. Doesn't seem like I can use topics for this, so probably need a way to query for users?

Comment: What you're asking for is known as a geoquery. The common way to do this is by using a GeoFire library, such as this one https://pub.dev/packages/geo_firestore

Answer (score 7):

1. save users locations in firestore (using geolocator plugin)
2. get current user location (using geolocator plugin)
3. Calculate the distance between the user and other users (using geolocator plugin)

   ```
   Geolocator().distanceBetween();
   ```
4. Put a condition as example if(distance < 200) show users
5. send a notification to the selected user (Firebase Cloud Messaging)

Sorry I couldn't give more details because they are many questions.